# How to access the i18n instance in a store/action in nuxt?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I have a typescript Vue.js app using vue-i18n and I want to port it to Nuxt.js. In the Vue.js app, I initialized i18n in a file by calling

```
// Create VueI18n instance with options
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'ja', // set locale
  messages, // set locale messages
})
```

To access the i18n instance from code locations (Vue actions etc.) where there is no access to `{{ $t('my.translation.key' }}` as in templates, I exported the `i18n` object from the file where I instantiated it and then accessed it by calling `i18n.t('my.translation.key')` to retrieve translations and other properties like the current active language.

Now, with nuxt.js and nuxt-i18n, there is no such explicit initialization and everything happens "magically" by configuring nuxt-i18n in the Nuxt config.

How can I then access the i18n instance in actions/other code locations outside of templates?
I tried to use just `this.$i18n.t(...)` but this did not work. Also, if I `import Vue from 'vue'` and try to call it via `Vue.$i18n.t(...)` it did not work. How can I get access to the i18n instance?